# Stuck in login loop Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: login, login-screen

I’m stuck in a login loop after rebooting. 
I enter the correct password but it just kicks me back. I cannot post the screenshots yet.

I already booted in recovery mode and changed password. I fixed from terminal packages with Aeolus commands such as sudo dpkg—configure
I always have the same problem. 
I googled and the solutions provided even here in askubuntu do not work. 
Furthermore login screen occasionally gets green as stated in various posts, so I checked all the proprietary drivers in Ubuntu settings for my MBP retina 15’ 2014 and are correctly installed and updated.
I have no idea.
Ubuntu is my only OS on that machine

Comment: Please show `lsb_release -rd`

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 at login screen and login into the shell. once the terminal is open install nvideia driver using the cmd **sudo apt install nvidia-384** and reboot the machine the above steps worked for me when i have the same issue but with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It is not working. I already reset and reinstalled Ubuntu but same problem: once I close the lid or reboot or switch off I get stuck in that loop: my credentials are not recognized and that green screen

Comment: No answers..not what I expected when reading Ubuntu most supported Linux distro..